# Magento Free Shipping Promotion

Tags: magento

I want to set up a shopping cart rule in Magento that offers free shipping on orders over £20, €20 or $20

How would I go about this, as I could set it to subtotal of 20 but this takes in account currency conversion

I thought I could perhaps do

```
if subtotal is 20 and country = (all the countries that use euros) ||
if subtotal is 20 and country = (all USA) ||
if subtotal is 20 and country = (all GB)
```

though this seems long winded, is there a better way?

Comment: if it works what is the problem?

Comment: Hi, try to work with this method importShippingRate in mage_dir/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Rate.php. You can get subtotal from quote and apply shipping discount based on country code.

Comment: Check out this extension http://www.webshopapps.com/productmatrix-shipping-extension.html does exactly this, managed via .csv file